# react-native android run error

Tags: android, react-native

run-android error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7flI.png)

When I want to use react-native-camera,run-android like this,but react-native start is successful
react-native version  49.5

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the react-native-camera module you added. Did you clean your gradle by running `cd android && .\gradlew clean` after installing native module? Also make sure you have linked the rncamera module by editing the .java files.

Comment: Start android studio and install 26.0.2 SDK version.

Comment: Did you start any AVD or connected any physical device with your machine before starting your app?